# Equivalent to 'cut' on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file which has entries as below.

```
/a/b/c/d/e/f
/a/b/c/g/k/l/f/j/h
/a/b/c/i/m/n/p
```

I need a command in Windows which would remove the `'/a/b/c'` part from the file.

The output file should look like

```
d/e/f
g/k/l/f/j/h
i/m/n/p
```

I tried using the `for` command with `/` as the delimiter, but I couldn't get the expected result.
How can I do this?

Comment: there is a windows port of cut http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Comment: I get this error 'cut' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @user3437212 did you download the GnuWin32 package? Did you put the tools into your `PATH` variable?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Isn't there any other way this can be done? without installing the gnuwin32 package? I dont have previleges to install packages on the system that I'm working on currently :(

Comment: I don't think so. But what's the problem with "installing" it? Download the zip-file, unzip it, done.

Comment: Consider UnxUtils as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@echo off

(for /f "tokens=3,* delims=/" %%a in (input.txt) do echo %%b) > output.txt
```

And the "trick" is to ask for the third token and the rest of the line.

To use it directly from the command line:

```
(for /f "tokens=3,* delims=/" %a in (input.txt) do @echo %b) > output.txt
```

The escaped percent signs are simplified and, as from command line the `echo off` is not enabled by default, the `@` before `echo` is needed.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for! thanks!
%%b is a typo? I seem to get wrong result when i give echo %%a !!

Comment: Cool trick.  Wicked notation.   So the above is not a typo.  For each 'token' pulled out from the delimiter, it's assigned to the first letter in the series, %%a, and the code automatically assigns subsequent matches to incremented variables %%b, %%c,...and so on.  I don't know if it always has to start with %%a.  So the trick used above takes the (3)rd token, followed by all other tokens (*).  This gets assigned to %%a and %%b respectively.  Since you wanted everything that trails /a/b/c, you want the second match for output, which is %%b.  %%a just serves as a positional anchor.

Comment: how do I use it in a piped operation? I have this for Linux: svn info | grep "Revision:" | cut -d':' -f2 that gives me the "102" from the string "Revision: 102" and I need the equivalent in Windows BAT file. So far I have; svn info | findstr "Revision:" and that works fine, but I don't know how to pipe the result to the for to isolate the number from the word.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell:

```
get-content test.txt | foreach-object {
  $_ -replace '/a/b/c/',''
} | out-file test2.txt
```