# How to very efficiently extract specific pattern from characters?

Tags: regex, r

I have  big data like this :

```
> Data[1:7,1]
[1] mature=hsa-miR-5087|mir_Family=-|Gene=OR4F5        
[2] mature=hsa-miR-26a-1-3p|mir_Family=mir-26|Gene=OR4F9
[3] mature=hsa-miR-448|mir_Family=mir-448|Gene=OR4F5   
[4] mature=hsa-miR-659-3p|mir_Family=-|Gene=OR4F5      
[5] mature=hsa-miR-5197-3p|mir_Family=-|Gene=OR4F5     
[6] mature=hsa-miR-5093|mir_Family=-|Gene=OR4F5        
[7] mature=hsa-miR-650|mir_Family=mir-650|Gene=OR4F5
```

what I want to do is that, in every row, I want to select the name after word **mature=** and also the word after **Gene=** and then pater them together with

```
paste(a,b, sep="-")
```

for example, the expected output from first two rows would be like :

```
hsa-miR-5087-OR4F5
hsa-miR-26a-1-3p-OR4F9
```

so, the final implementation is like this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Data)){
    Data[i,3] <- sub("mature=([^|]*).*Gene=(.*)", "\\1-\\2", Data[i,1])
    Name <- strsplit(as.vector(Data[i,2]),"\\|")[[1]][2]
    Data[i,4] <- as.numeric(sub("pvalue=","",Name))
    print(i)
}
```

which work well, but it's very slow. the size of **Data** is very big and it has **200,000,000**  rows. this implementation is very slow for that. how can I speed it up ?

Comment: We don't have `Data` so when formulating questions like this it is better to show the data like this:  `x <- Data[1:7, 1]; dput(x)`

Comment: your edit made this a little bit of a moving target -- it wasn't initially clear that you needed a computationally efficient solution.  I would encourage you to post your own answer to this question that shows benchmarks for a reasonably large data set (e.g. try it on the first 100,000 rows of your data set) for *all* of the answers provided below, following the format given in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747426/how-to-efficiently-read-the-first-character-from-each-line-of-a-text-file/).

Comment: You might also check out the [stringi package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html), which is intended for fast string processing, and the `data.table` and or `dplyr` packages

Answer (score 11):

If you can guarantee that the format is exactly as you specified, then a regular expression can capture (denoted by the brackets below) everything from the equals sign upto the pipe symbol, and from the Gene= to the end, and paste them together with a minus sign:

```
sub("mature=([^|]*).*Gene=(.*)", "\\1-\\2", Data[,1])
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use `read.table` with `=` as a separator then pasting the 2 columns:

```
res = read.table(text=txt,sep='=')
paste(sub('[|].*','',res$V2),            ## get rid from last part here
      sub('^ +| +$','',res$V4),sep='-')  ## remove extra spaces 

[1] "hsa-miR-5087-OR4F5"     "hsa-miR-26a-1-3p-OR4F9" "hsa-miR-448-OR4F5"      "hsa-miR-659-3p-OR4F5"  
[5] "hsa-miR-5197-3p-OR4F5"  "hsa-miR-5093-OR4F5"     "hsa-miR-650-OR4F5"
```

Answer (score 5):

The simple `sub` solution already given looks quite nice but just in case here are some other approaches:

**1) read.pattern**  Using `read.pattern` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) we can parse the data into a data.frame.  This intermediate form, `DF`, can then be manipulated in many ways.  In this case we use `paste` in essentially the same way as in the question:

```
library(gsubfn)
DF <- read.pattern(text = Data[, 1], pattern = "(\\w+)=([^|]*)")
paste(DF$V2, DF$V6, sep = "-")
```

giving:

```
[1] "hsa-miR-5087-OR4F5"     "hsa-miR-26a-1-3p-OR4F9" "hsa-miR-448-OR4F5"     
[4] "hsa-miR-659-3p-OR4F5"   "hsa-miR-5197-3p-OR4F5"  "hsa-miR-5093-OR4F5"    
[7] "hsa-miR-650-OR4F5"
```

The intermediate data frame, `DF`, that was produced looks like this:

```
> DF
      V1               V2         V3      V4   V5    V6
1 mature     hsa-miR-5087 mir_Family       - Gene OR4F5
2 mature hsa-miR-26a-1-3p mir_Family  mir-26 Gene OR4F9
3 mature      hsa-miR-448 mir_Family mir-448 Gene OR4F5
4 mature   hsa-miR-659-3p mir_Family       - Gene OR4F5
5 mature  hsa-miR-5197-3p mir_Family       - Gene OR4F5
6 mature     hsa-miR-5093 mir_Family       - Gene OR4F5
7 mature      hsa-miR-650 mir_Family mir-650 Gene OR4F5
```

Here is a visualization of the regular expression we used:

```
(\w+)=([^|]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bDmynskQ3Xcsm6gU)

**1a) names** We could make `DF` look nicer by reading the three columns of data and the three names separately. This also improves the `paste` statement:

```
DF <- read.pattern(text = Data[, 1], pattern = "=([^|]*)")
names(DF) <- unlist(read.pattern(text = Data[1,1], pattern = "(\\w+)=", as.is = TRUE))

paste(DF$mature, DF$Gene, sep = "-") # same answer as above
```

The `DF` in this section that was produced looks like this.  It has 3 instead of 6 columns and remaining columns were used to determine appropriate column names:

```
> DF
            mature mir_Family  Gene
1     hsa-miR-5087          - OR4F5
2 hsa-miR-26a-1-3p     mir-26 OR4F9
3      hsa-miR-448    mir-448 OR4F5
4   hsa-miR-659-3p          - OR4F5
5  hsa-miR-5197-3p          - OR4F5
6     hsa-miR-5093          - OR4F5
7      hsa-miR-650    mir-650 OR4F5
```

**2) strapplyc**

Another approach using the same package.  This extracts the fields coming after a = and not containing a | producing a list.  We then sapply over that list pasting the first and third fields together:

```
sapply(strapplyc(Data[, 1], "=([^|]*)"), function(x) paste(x[1], x[3], sep = "-"))
```

giving the same result.

Here is a visualization of the regular expression used:

```
=([^|]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mpvieyxXJjZwJLVc)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach:

```
Data <- readLines(n = 7)
mature=hsa-miR-5087|mir_Family=-|Gene=OR4F5        
mature=hsa-miR-26a-1-3p|mir_Family=mir-26|Gene=OR4F9
mature=hsa-miR-448|mir_Family=mir-448|Gene=OR4F5   
mature=hsa-miR-659-3p|mir_Family=-|Gene=OR4F5      
mature=hsa-miR-5197-3p|mir_Family=-|Gene=OR4F5     
mature=hsa-miR-5093|mir_Family=-|Gene=OR4F5        
mature=hsa-miR-650|mir_Family=mir-650|Gene=OR4F5
df <- read.table(sep = "|", text = Data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
l <- lapply(df, strsplit, "=")
trim <- function(x) gsub("^\\s*|\\s*$", "", x)
paste(trim(sapply(l[[1]], "[", 2)), trim(sapply(l[[3]], "[", 2)), sep = "-")
# [1] "hsa-miR-5087-OR4F5"     "hsa-miR-26a-1-3p-OR4F9" "hsa-miR-448-OR4F5"      "hsa-miR-659-3p-OR4F5"   "hsa-miR-5197-3p-OR4F5"  "hsa-miR-5093-OR4F5"    
# [7] "hsa-miR-650-OR4F5"
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not the more elegant but you can try :

```
sapply(Data[,1],function(x){
                   parts<-strsplit(x,"\\|")[[1]]
                   y<-paste(gsub("(mature=)|(Gene=)","",parts[grepl("mature|Gene",parts)]),collapse="-")
                   return(y)
                })
```

**Example**

```
 Data<-data.frame(col1=c("mature=hsa-miR-5087|mir_Family=-|Gene=OR4F5","mature=hsa-miR-26a-1-3p|mir_Family=mir-26|Gene=OR4F9"),col2=1:2,stringsAsFactors=F)

> Data[,1]
[1] "mature=hsa-miR-5087|mir_Family=-|Gene=OR4F5"          "mature=hsa-miR-26a-1-3p|mir_Family=mir-26|Gene=OR4F9"

> sapply(Data[,1],function(x){
+                        parts<-strsplit(x,"\\|")[[1]]
+                        y<-paste(gsub("(mature=)|(Gene=)","",parts[grepl("mature|Gene",parts)]),collapse="-")
+                        return(y)
+                     })
         mature=hsa-miR-5087|mir_Family=-|Gene=OR4F5 mature=hsa-miR-26a-1-3p|mir_Family=mir-26|Gene=OR4F9 
                                "hsa-miR-5087-OR4F5"                             "hsa-miR-26a-1-3p-OR4F9"
```