# skip lines in reading files using reg ex

Tags: r, read.csv

i have files with similar contents

```
!software version: $Revision$
!date: 07/06/2016 $ 
!
! from Mouse Genome Database (MGD) & Gene Expression Database (GXD)
!
MGI
```

I am using read.csv to read the files. But I need to skip the lines with "!" in the beginning. How can I do that?

Comment: You can set the `skip` parameter, but it just takes an integer of lines to skip. You could calculate that number with `readLines` and `grep` if you're doing it programmatically or a lot, but otherwise it's probably easiest to just look at the file.

Comment: I have multiple files, and its not consistent in all the files. Sometimes its 12, sometimes its 45. thats why I cant use skip

Comment: You could use one of the answers from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747426/how-to-efficiently-read-the-first-character-from-each-line-of-a-text-file) to determine which lines start with `!`, then use `read.csv`'s `skip` argument based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read.csv` function and `read.table` that it is based on have an argument called `comment.char` which can be used to specify a character that if seen will ignore the rest of that line.  Setting that to "!" may be enough to do what you want.

If you really need a regular expression, then the best approach is to read the file using `readLines` (or similar function), then apply the regular expression to the resulting vector of character strings to drop to unwanted elements (rows), then pass the result to the `text` argument to `read.table` (or use a text connection).

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the first line that doesn't start with a `!`,

```
to_skip <- min(grep('^[^!]', trimws(readLines('file.csv'))))

df <- read.csv('file.csv', skip = to_skip)
```