# Reading a file from a position in R

Tags: r, string, dna-sequence, systemtime

I have a large plain text file to be read in R, where all data is contained at the same line with no spaces (DNA sequence with no header). I found the next function:

```
readChar("filename",nchar=n)
```

which allows to read just the "n" first elements of the file saving a lot of time. Is there another function in R that goes further by reading just from START position to STOP one, avoiding to upload the whole file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically no, from what i know, you need to read the whole file and then discard the characters that you don't want. For example, if you want only the first 10 letters for every line:

```
strsub(readChar("filename",nchar=n),1,10)
```

But, this post ([How to efficiently read the first character from each line of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747426/how-to-efficiently-read-the-first-character-from-each-line-of-a-text-file)) shows some ways of improving the efficiency of that.

Comment: Thank you Ricardo, I did not find this post, It was what I was looking for but, unfortunately, It seems not be possible reading a file from a no start position. Anyway, readChar instead of scan, improves the execution time a lot. On the other hand, I do not find any differences between stri_sub from stringi and substring from base for large files reading. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a connexion, then use the seek function.  Do not forget to close the connexion after.

For example, this will read 100 characters from position 1000.

```
cx <- file("filename", "rb")
seek(cx, 1000)
d <- readChar(cx, nchar=100)
close(cx)
```