# Reading a file that has non fixed number of columns fread() in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to read a file which in default is supposed to have 7 columns but probably there might be some commas within some strings which is causing other rows to have more than 7 columns.
Regardless of which info that is in other columns my only goal is to read the first 7 columns. However, fread is not reading the whole file even after adding the argument `select = 1:7`

```
> data <- fread("dpp.DAT",header=FALSE, fill=T, select = 1:7, sep=", ",stringsAsFactors = F)
```

```
Warning message:
In fread("dpp.DAT", header = FALSE, fill=T, select = 1:7,sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = F) :
  Stopped early on line 45922. Expected 7 fields but found 8. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<84172666,DS,BRAND 4 - DERIVATIVE,#PL LOC BDD  :  BDD - BRAND 3 - DERIVATIVE,37324,BLEND-A-MD-INSPRD-BY-NTR-SGHH,BLEND B MAR INSPIRED BY OTHER CHAMOMILE, VAG + HHHH>>
```

Is there trick you can suggest to read all the rows of the file?

[Sample dataset](https://github.com/Macosso/Test_R_fread)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say we have a text file `"test.txt"` like this:

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i,j
k,l,m
```

We can read it in and set `FILL=T` and then subset the final column out:

```
> fread("test.txt", fill=T)[,-4]
   V1 V2 V3
1:  a  b  c
2:  d  e  f
3:  g  h  i
4:  k  l  m
```

Or, set `select=1:3`:

```
> fread("test.txt", fill=T, select = 1:3)
   V1 V2 V3
1:  a  b  c
2:  d  e  f
3:  g  h  i
4:  k  l  m
```

EDIT

The solution was to use the `cut` unix command as such:

```
terminal$ cut Test_Fread_column.DAT -d',' -f1-7 > tmp
R> fread("tmp")
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question, but I already attempted to provide argument ```fill=T``` but I still get the same error

Comment: @Macosso probably this will be hard to fix unless you provide a sample of the data. Can you post a reduced subset of the data, including the offending lines?

Comment: You can use the following dataset to test https://github.com/Macosso/Test_R_fread

Comment: OK. It was easier just to do ``cut Test_Fread_column.DAT -d',' -f1-7 > tmp`` (in the unix shell) and then ``fread("tmp")``, which worked fine.

Comment: can you just update your answer with this command so that it can get approved. Also can you share the command for windows CMD if you have have?

Comment: Don't know the windows command, but check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25067069/5784757) out.

Answer (score 3):

`data.table` gets finicky about the extra columns showing up in the middle as opposed to the beginning so that's why using `select` and `fill` don't work here.  What you can do is take all the rows it gives you up front and then try again with `skip` on the rows you've already loaded.  On that second (or more) attempt the extra columns will now be in the beginning so `fill` and `select` work as expected.  There are probably more elegant ways to do the following but this works

```
library(data.table)

#capture warnings so we can evaluate what happened last in code
tempfile='tmp321364.txt' 
conn<-file(tempfile, open="r+")
sink(file=conn, type='message')

DT<-list()
while(TRUE) {
  DT[[length(DT)+1]] <- fread(filename, header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors = F, fill=T, select=1:7, skip=ifelse(length(DT)>0,sum(sapply(DT, nrow)),0))
  if(nrow(DT[[length(DT)]])==0) break
  warns<-readLines(conn)
  if(length(warns)==3) { #The warning about extra columns is 3 lines long
    DT[[length(DT)+1]]<-  fread(filename, header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors = F, fill=T, select=1:7, skip=sum(sapply(DT, nrow)))
    if(nrow(DT[[length(DT)]])==0) break
  } else { #an error about skipping too many rows is not 3 lines, assuming away other issues
    break
  }
}
DT<-rbindlist(DT)
sink(NULL, type='message')
close(conn)
rm(tempfile)
```

With your exact data, you don't need the `while(TRUE)` loop but if, for example, there were a 10th column that shows up even further down then this will work for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

Dean's answer  provides more automation than mine. Whenever I hit this problem (which is actually probably poorly formatted data), I resort to manually finding and then rebuilding the extract with rbind:

```
s1 <- fread("Extract.txt",
    nrows=674170,
    strip.white = TRUE,
    fill = TRUE,
    blank.lines.skip = TRUE,
    encoding="UTF-8")

s2 <- fread("Extract.txt",
    strip.white = TRUE,
    fill = TRUE,
    blank.lines.skip = TRUE,
    skip=674170,
    encoding="UTF-8")
# ad.infinitum until you complete "Extract.txt"
s3 <- rbind(s1,s2)
rm(s1)
rm(s2)
```